# ASP.NET Core Razor pages friendly URL

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

The URLs of the articles look like this:

```
http://localhost:5153/Content/Article?title=The%20Statistic%20Article
```

but I want them to look like this:

```
http://localhost:5153/Content/Article/the-statistic-article or http://localhost:5153/Content/the-statistic-article
```

The content of the article is contained in `Article.cshtml`.

How can I make this happen?

Page model:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetArticleAsync(int id)
{
    Article = await _context.Articles
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

    if (Article == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
        
    return new JsonResult(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Page("Article", new { title = Article.Title }), articleData = Article });
}
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'Article?handler=Article',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id: id }, 
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.redirectToUrl) {

                localStorage.setItem('articleData', JSON.stringify(response.articleData));
                window.location.href = response.redirectToUrl;
            }
        },

        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            // Handle errors here
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#route-templates

Comment: The default route already matches your URL. You're passing the title as the `id` value. *Both* URLs  would work if you changed `int id` to `string title` and the template to use `title` instead of `id`. You need to reconsider the shape of the URLs you want. Do you want to get articles by ID or only by title? What do you want the different URLs to look like? All options can be handled using different route templates. There's no need for friendly URLs.